# Joomla main content does not show up

Tags: html, joomla2.5, joomla-template

In the last few days I have set up a Website using joomla. ATM I am linking menus, articles and modules.
In the template, the content position is marked using:

```
<jdoc:include type="component" />
```

This is where articles should be rendered.
When klicking a menu item type:single article, there is no content rendered in the component area on the main site.
the only possibility to show articles in the "component" position is using a menu type:featured articles.
how can I get content shown at the component position without using featured articles?

does anyone know this problem?

EDIT: this is the content of index.php:
here is the whole content of the index.php:

```
<!--<?php
    defined("_JEXEC") or die("Restricted Access");
    JHTML::_("behavior.framework", true);
    $app = JFactory::getApplication();
    $pathtotemplate = $this->baseurl."/templates/".$this->template;
?>-->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <jdoc:include type="head" />
        <meta http-equiv='content-type' content='text/html; charset=UTF-8'>
        <meta charset='utf-8'>
        <link rel="icon" href="<?php echo $pathtotemplate ?>/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
        <!-- own Javascripts -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $pathtotemplate ?>/js/custom.js"></script>
        <!-- Google Analytics -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $pathtotemplate ?>/js/google.js"></script>
        <!-- system CSS Files -->
        <link rel='stylesheet' href="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/system/css/system.css" type="text/css" />
        <link rel='stylesheet' href="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/system/css/general.css" type="text/css" />
        <!-- own CSS Files -->
        <link rel='stylesheet' href="<?php echo $pathtotemplate ?>/css/template.css" type="text/css" />

        <!-- delete this file after developement -->
        <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='css/template.css' />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="site">
            <header>
                <div id='placeholder'>&nbsp;</div>
                <div id='logo'>
                    <a href="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/" accesskey="h" tabindex="1">
                        <img src="<?php echo $pathtotemplate ?>/images/logo.png" width="178" height="260" name="Logo" alt="Logo von sattler energie consulting" />
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div id='headmenu'>
                    <div id='checken'>
                        <div class="headmenu">
                            <img src="<?php echo $pathtotemplate ?>/images/headmenu/rund/headmenu_rund_blank.png" />
                            <img src="<?php echo $pathtotemplate ?>/images/headmenu/rund/headmenu_rund_01.png" />
                            <div><jdoc:include type="modules" name="checken" /></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id='optimieren'>
                        <div class="headmenu">
                            <img src="<?php echo $pathtotemplate ?>/images/headmenu/rund/headmenu_rund_blank.png" />
                            <img src="<?php echo $pathtotemplate ?>/images/headmenu/rund/headmenu_rund_02.png" />
                            <div><jdoc:include type="modules" name="optimieren" /></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id='erhalten'>
                        <div class="headmenu">
                            <img src="<?php echo $pathtotemplate ?>/images/headmenu/rund/headmenu_rund_blank.png" />
                            <img src="<?php echo $pathtotemplate ?>/images/headmenu/rund/headmenu_rund_03.png" />
                            <div><jdoc:include type="modules" name="erhalten" /></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id='leben'>
                        <div class="headmenu">
                            <img src="<?php echo $pathtotemplate ?>/images/headmenu/rund/headmenu_rund_blank.png" />
                            <img src="<?php echo $pathtotemplate ?>/images/headmenu/rund/headmenu_rund_04.png" />
                            <div><jdoc:include type="modules" name="leben" /></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id='subhead' class="border-radius"><h1><jdoc:include type="modules" name="subhead" /></h1></div>
            </header>
            <div id='content'>
                <div id='leftmenu'><jdoc:include type="modules" name="leftmenu" /></div>
                <div id='main'>
                    <jdoc:include type="module" name="breadcrumbs" />
                    <jdoc:include type="message" />
                    <jdoc:include type="component" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <footer>
                <div id='inner_footer' class="border-radius"><jdoc:include type="modules" name="footer" /></div>
            </footer>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I assume you have created your own template? Your problem looks like it is filtering what's on the frontpage. Switch templates and find out if the same happens, if it doesn't then it's your template that has the problem.

Comment: @jackJoe yes, it's self-created. do I have to create a module for the component position?
in beez2 every article shows up as wanted. I don't know about filters in a template. what do you mean by my template filters what's on the frontopage?

Comment: No, your code should work as expected. Please post the full code of your template (index.php) and make sure you have selected that template as the default for the entire site (for this problem solving at least). Aditionally, does the PHP error log display anything when using your template?

Comment: @jackJoe There are no errors in the error log according to the Template I use.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried the template code you supplied, and the solution is very simple:

Remove the name of the component.

From:

```
<jdoc:include type="component" name="component" />
```

Change to:

```
<jdoc:include type="component" />
```

Comment: Does this solution work in your case? I still get no content rendered, but in beez2 it works.

Comment: @baerbjoern  Yes it works, I tried it before posting the answer. If I left the name of the component (not supposed to be there) it wouldn't display anything, when I removed it, it worked correctly. Are you sure the template is the default?

Comment: Yes, my template is the default site template. defined it in "Template Manager: Styles"

Comment: http://wp11056354.wp372.webpack.hosteurope.de/sec/
News menu uses featured articles --> works - 
every other Menu Item uses  the single Article Type, this does not work.

Comment: @baerbjoern looking at your link I can't find out the problem. I just retried your template code (without the name in the component) and it works for every case, home, single, menu, all...

Comment: can you see text being rendered in the main part (under the breadcrumbs) when you click an item in the menu at my link?

Comment: @baerbjoern no I can't and there is nothing at the code rendered... That's very odd.

Comment: This is my problem. I have written the joomla position as you said, but there is no output when selecting "single article"... The Menu Items are all linked to their corresponding Articles.

Comment: @baerbjoern I have no more ideas, sorry.